# HeadSpin authorisation issue to connect with remote device

Tags: automation, appium, xctestcase, headspin

We are trying to connect Headspin remote device using Xcode.
As per headspin documentation used below line to connect with headspin remote iOS device but facing authorisation issue as mentioned below.

hs connect -t 0879s6hca3cb4181b6e30ae67sfstes (host address).headspin.io

"ERROR: You are not authorized to perform this action. Please make sure that your API token is correct, corresponding permissions up to date and that you are connecting to the right API backend."

Any help could be appreciated. Thanks in advance